# Filter multiple choice only if logic

Tags: python

Suppose I have a table with 2 columns. First column has Name and second has region. ABC is presenting HK and SG. XYZ is only in SG.

User can input only region.
Let say if user selects SG then XYZ should be output. And ABC can be output only in both HK and SG in entered. If only HK is entered no output.

| Name | region |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | HK |
| ABC | SG |
| XYZ | SG |

I tried in Excel filter but no help. Can this be done in Excel or python?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating keys from the region, whatever the user enters, sorting it, and concatenating it. Store data in a dict list, so each region combination can give you all result possible {'HKSG' : ['ABC'], 'SG' : ['XYZ']}, so if user selects HK and SG, display list corresponding 'HKSG'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and let me know if it works? Do you have xlsx file or csv file? Since, the data is not provided, I cannot try it.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("table.xlsx") # inser here the path of your file. change table.xlsx witht he name of your file.

region = input("Enter region: ")

filtered_df = df[df["region"]==region]

names = filtered_df["Name"].tolist()

if len(names) == 0:
    print("No data exists in that region")
else:
    print("Names in", region, "region:", ", ".join(names))
```

Comment: Let me try and respond back. Thanks for the help

Comment: @SurajGhorai please upvote and choose my answer as correct  if it worked